# Por qual motivo não consigo consultar por um objeto adicionado antes do SaveChanges?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Eu preciso adicionar vários objetos ao banco e alguns objetos precisam de outro objeto específico que eu adicionei anteriormente.

Quando faço uma consulta para obter o objeto, ele vem nulo.

**Exemplo:**

```
var subItem = new SubItem
{
  Valor1 = 1,
  Valor2 = "Qualquer coisa"
};
repositorioSubItem.Inserir(subItem);

var item = new Item
{
  Etc = "Oi",
  SubItem = repositorioSubItem.Buscar(e => e.Valor1 = 1); //Valor NULL aqui
};
repositorioItem.Inserir(item);

contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Qual o motivo de não conseguir obtê-lo?

O que preciso fazer para consultar antes de um `SaveChanges`?

---

**Método `Buscar`:**

```
public TEntidade Buscar(Expression<Func<TEntidade, bool>> criterios)
{
    return Entidades.Where(criterios).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Como está seu método `Buscar`?

Comment: Irei editar a pergunta e adicionar o que tem no meu `Buscar`.

Comment: @bigown, editei a pergunta e `Entidades` é um DbSet da entidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filipe,

Como Tiago Cesar informou, você não pode realizar uma consulta ao banco de dados contando com as entidades inseridas no contexto enquanto não executar o comando SaveChanges, pois estas estão 'marcadas' como Added mas instrução insert ainda não foi executada. Deste modo, a qualquer momento você pode dar um 'Rollback' e descartar todas as operações que foram realizadas no contexto, em vez de executar um `SaveChanges`.

Você pode buscar pelas entidades que estão com o status **Added** mas ainda não foram inseridas (através do `SaveChanges`) utilizando a propriedade `Local` do `DbSet`. Seu código ficaria assim:

```
  public TEntidade BuscarLocal(Func<TEntidade,bool> criterios)
  {
      return Entidades.Local.Where(criterios).SingleOrDefault();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Bem, em `SubItem = repositorioSubItem.Buscar(e => e.Valor1 = 1);` você está mandando buscar no contexto por um item que não está lá, já que o `SaveChanges()` não foi ainda executado. Isso resulta em uma query `SQL` que não encontra dados (já que eles ainda não foram salvos).No seu caso, nada te impede de consumir `subItem` já que ele está instanciado em memória.

Isso acontece porque o Entity Framework encapsula as operações em transações. Chamar o `SaveChanges()` efetivamente dispara os `INSERT` ou `UPDATE` necessários para persistir os dados.

Comment: Entendi o motivo de não conseguir pesquisar o objeto, mas ainda assim no cenário real eu tenho uma lista e um foreach. Esse subItem específico com o `Valor1` não existe mais e precisaria do que eu tinha acabado de inserir na iteração anterior.